# lxc container shutdown on ubuntu make the system stop to work

Tags: ubuntu

I have a lxc container that works like a php and mysql server. When I do:

```
sudo lxc-shutdown -n [name of container]
```

All my system stops to work. The only thing I can do is turn off the computer directly on the button, because the ubuntu don't respond more any command after the shutdown process of the lxc container. This problem became boring, because all the time that I need turn off my lxc container my computer stops to wrok too. How can I fix this issues?

Thanks

The version of my ubuntu is 13.04. 
I created this container in a simple way:

```
lxc-create -n ubuntu-server
```

And I started to use.

The following is my config file of the container:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:e0:00:ee
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up

lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/ubuntu-server/rootfs
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/ubuntu-server/fstab
lxc.pivotdir = lxc_putold

lxc.devttydir = lxc
lxc.tty = 4
lxc.pts = 1024

lxc.utsname = ubuntu-server
lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.cap.drop = sys_module mac_admin mac_override

# When using LXC with apparmor, uncomment the next line to run unconfined:
#lxc.aa_profile = unconfined

lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = a
# Allow any mknod (but not using the node)
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c *:* m
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b *:* m
# /dev/null and zero
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:3 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:5 rwm
# consoles
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:1 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:0 rwm
#lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:0 rwm
#lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:1 rwm
# /dev/{,u}random
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:9 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:8 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 136:* rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:2 rwm
# rtc
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 254:0 rwm
#fuse
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:229 rwm
#tun
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm
#full
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:7 rwm
#hpet
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:228 rwm
#kvm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:232 rwm
```

My fstab file of the container (cat /var/lib/lxc/ubuntu-server/fstab):

```
proc            proc         proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
sysfs           sys          sysfs defaults  0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

From outside the container use the `lxc-` commands.

```
sudo lxc-shutdown -n CN
```

Ref:  [Ubuntu 13.04 » Ubuntu Server Guide » Virtualization » LXC](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/lxc.html)

Comment: Yes, I did  always in this way: sudo lxc-shutdown -n CN.
And one other thing, no matter I  do the shutdown inside the container or outside, I get this trouble always